# I want to send email notification when three similar cases are created for a account in a single day. It's working but how to do using Map

Tags: apex, map

I have written code and it is working , but I want to improve code using MAP instead of multiple for loop.
Scenario is

1. Send notification when three cases with specific values created in a week for Same account.
2. Send notification when three cases are created in a same day for a specific account.

---

```
trigger CaseNotification on Case (after insert) {
    if(trigger.isAfter)
        {
        if(trigger.isInsert)
           {
              CaseCountAlertHelper .checkCaseCount(trigger.new);
           }
        }
     }


    public class CaseCountAlertHelper {
    public static void checkCaseCount(List<case> newCase)
    {
        //Create List of account Id
            List<Id> accId=new List<ID>();
            integer count=0;
            integer thirdSameday=0;
            boolean send=False;
            for(case c1:newCase)
            {
                accId.add(c1.AccountId);
            }
            List<Case> caseInfo=[select Id,accountId,Product_Type__c,Case_Category__c,Sub_Category__c,Case_Action__c from case where accountId=:accId and Case_Action__c='Troubleshooting' and CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7];
            for(case c2:newCase)
            {
                for(case c3:caseInfo)
                {
                    if(c2.AccountId==c3.AccountId && c2.Product_Type__c==c3.Product_Type__c && c2.Case_Category__c==c3.Case_Category__c && c2.Sub_Category__c==c3.Sub_Category__c && c2.Case_Action__c==c3.Case_Action__c)
                    {
                        count=count+1;
                        system.debug('First For :Count='+count);
                    }
                    if(c2.AccountId==c3.AccountId && c2.Case_Action__c==c3.Case_Action__c)
                    {
                        thirdSameday=thirdSameday+1;
                    }
                    
                }
                
                if(count==3)
                       {
                        system.debug('Third Occourance In a week');
                        string Casesubject='Case Repetition Alert:This is 3rd Case created' ;
                        string body='              This is 3rd Case created in a Week with same Product Type,Catogary,Subcatogary.'+'\n'+'\n'+'1. Case Number='+c2.CaseNumber+'\n'+'2. Product Type='+c2.Product_Type__c+'\n'+'3. Catogary='+c2.Case_Category__c+'\n'+'4. Subcatogary='+c2.Sub_Category__c+'\n';
                        sendEmail(Casesubject,body);
                        send=True;   
                       }
                    if(thirdSameday==3 && send==False)
                       {
                         system.debug('Check 3rd in week logic');
                         checkFourCaseOCcurance(c2.AccountId);
                           break;
                       }
            }
        }
    public static void checkFourCaseOCcurance(string accountIds)
    {
        integer countC=0; 
        integer countC1=0;
        List<Case> caseFourthCheck=[select Id,CreatedDate from case where accountId=:accountIds and  CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7 ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];
        system.debug('size of caseFourthCheck='+caseFourthCheck.size());
       
        for(integer i=0;i<caseFourthCheck.size();i++)
        {
            for(integer j=0;j<caseFourthCheck.size();j++)
            {
                case case1=caseFourthCheck[i];
                case case2=caseFourthCheck[j];
                if(case1.CreatedDate.Date()==case2.CreatedDate.Date() && case1.Id!=case2.Id)
                {
                    countC=countC+1;
                }
                
            }
            if(countC==2 )
        {
                    system.debug('3 cases on same day Email');
                    string Casesubject='Scenario 2: 3 cases on same day and';
                    string body='Three cases are created in a day   ';
                    sendEmail(Casesubject,body);
                     break;
        }
        }
        
    }
    Public static void sendEmail(string Casesubject,string body)
    {
        string finalBody='Hello Team,'+'\n'+'\n'+body;
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.toAddresses = new String[] { 'abc@gmail.com'};
        message.subject = Casesubject;
        message.plainTextBody = finalBody;
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
        if (results[0].success) 
        {
            System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
        } else 
        {
            System.debug('The email failed to send: ' + results[0].errors[0].message);
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code **does not work** in bulk. Try inserting 200 records at once and see what happens. You'll end up with a LimitException, either a CPU limit, sendEmail invocation limit, or a SOQL query limit exception. It also generally doesn't work correctly in bulk, since, as you've observed, you're not using a map. Here's code that should be much closer to what you're looking for.

I'd also like to note in the below code, that `Messaging.sendEmail(messages)` will throw an exception if an error occurs, you should use `Messaging.sendEmail(messages, false)` to avoid exceptions.

```
public class CaseCountAlertHelper {
    public static Case createKey(Case record) {
        return new Case(
            AccountId=record.AccountId,
            Product_Type__c=record.Product_Type__c,
            Case_Category__c=record.Case_Category__c,
            Sub_Category__c=record.Sub_Category__c,
            Case_Action__c=record.Case_Action__c
        );
    }
    public static void checkCaseCount(Case[] cases) {
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Case, Integer> sameTypeCount = new Map<Case, Integer>();
        Map<Id, Integer> sameDayCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        Date today = Date.today();
        for(Case record: cases) {
            Case key = createKey(record);
            accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
            sameTypeCount.put(key, 0);
            sameDayCount.put(key, 0);
        }
        for(Case record: [SELECT CreatedDate, AccountId, Product_Type__c, Case_Category__c, Sub_Category__c FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :accountIds AND Case_Action__c = 'Troubleshooting' AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7]) {
            Case key = createKey(record);
            Integer thisSameDayCount = sameDayCount.get(record.AccountId);
            Integer thisSameTypeCount = sameTypeCount.get(key);
            if(record.CreatedDate.date() == today) {
                sameDayCount.put(record.AccountId, thisSameDayCount + 1);
            }
            if(thisSameTypeCount != null) {
                sameTypeCount.put(key, thisSameTypeCount + 1);
            }
        }
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
        for(Case record: cases) {
            Case key = createKey(record);
            if(sameDayCount.get(record.AccountId) > 2) {
                emails.add(createSameDayEmail(record));
            } else if(sameTypeCount.get(key) > 2) {
                emails.add(createSameTypeEmail(record));
            }
        }
        if(!emails.isEmpty()) {
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(emails, false);
            for(Messaging.SendEmailResult result: results) {
                if(result.isSuccess()) {
                    System.debug('Send email success!');
                } else {
                    System.debug('Send email failure: '+result.getError());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage createSameDayEmail(Case record) {
        // create message here, do not send yet...
    }
    static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage createSameTypeEmail(Case record) {
        // create message here, do not send yet...
    }
}
```